# create Collection<T>

Tags: c#

In my project I want to create my own DataGrid, but I don't know from which object I want to create the columns of.

So I want a property:

```
private List<T> DataSource
```

Someone who has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: ...fix what? Can you be more explicit in your question?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided very much code or explanation, but I'm guessing you're getting a compiler error on that line regarding the generic parameter. You'll need to make your class declaration generic to also accept a parameter T.  Like this:

```
public class MyDataGridWrapper<T> : DataGrid
{

    private List<T> DataSource;
    ...
    ...

}
```

You haven't really specified what's wrong though, so I'm just guessing at both the error you're getting and what's actually wrong.

Comment: I want to set the datasource so i can create the columns for my grid

Example:
List<Dummy> items = new List<Dummy>();
Datasource = items;

how do i know that the object in my List<> is Dummy? so i can create columns for each property (with reflection)

Comment: You know it's a Dummy because it's a List<Dummy>().  You can't just have a List<T> without getting T from somewhere though.

Comment: the fact is that i also will create objects with reflection, so i wil not know what type it is when i'm writing my code..

So what i want to do --> DataSource =List<OBJECTYPE>();
and then generate my columns automaticly without.

1) The first question is, how can i make my Datasource as <T> list
2) second question: how can i get the type of my objects in the list, even when there are no items in my list (empty list, count =0)..

Comment: I answered your first question, and your second question would be better asked in a separate thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into `IBindingList<T>.`  This interface is intended to be for lists that will be used in databinding.  Your property should be of this type then, anything that implents this type can be used to bind to your grid.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just leave it as "object" and cast it?

Comment: If you go this route, you lose type-checking.

Comment: i tried is as object, but have no idea when  i want to make my columns, how i can get the type that's in te list?

example:

List<object> DataSource = new List<object>()
DataSource.Add(new Dummy(){Name ="test", value =1};

how can i know in my function createColumns that the objects in my list are object of the Dummy class? And what to do when my list is empty (.Count = 0) ?

Comment: Type safety: the compiler will find type mismatches for you. And you won't have to type the ((SomeClassName) ...) casts.

Comment: Have no idea what you mean? :)